# How to disable TLSv1 and enable TLSv1.2 in apache 2.2.29

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

Iam using Redhat 7.3/Apache 2.2.29/Openssl 1.0.1e-fips

I have to remediate a vulnerability(SSL/TLS Server supports TLSv1.0) in Apache. I tried to add line "SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1" in my httpd.conf file and restarted httpd. But it throws below error.

Error : SSLProtocol: Illegal protocol '"TLSv1.1"'

Can anyone help me in this regard ?

Regards,

Aneesh

Answer (score 5):

From https://community.qualys.com/thread/13903:

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
```